# sigaction passes SIGINT to system call, but not signal

Tags: c, sockets, signals

I have a loop handling an `accept(2)` call. I want to be able to perform some cleanup when a `SIGINT` is sent to the program. My first thought was to use the `signal` function.

```
void signal_handler(int signal) {
    printf("Caught signal\n");
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, &signal_handler);
    // ...
    int accept_fd = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);
    if (accept_fd == -1) {
        close(sock);
        perror("accept");
        return 1;
    }
    // ...
}
```

However, this simply prints "Caught signal" and then the program continues on.

If I modify `main` to use `sigaction`, the program works as expected.

```
int main() {
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = &signal_handler;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
    // ...
    int accept_fd = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);
    if (accept_fd == -1) {
        close(sock);
        perror("accept");
        return 1;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Upon sending SIGINT, I get `Caught Signal`, followed by `accept: Interrupted system call`. From the man page for `accept(2)`

> ERRORS
>
> ...
>
> EINTR  The system call was interrupted by a signal that was caught before a valid connection arrived; see signal(7).

I understand that `sigaction` is more modern and that I should be using it over `signal`, but I'm quite curious why it provides this difference in functionality.

Below I've included a full usable example program for each case.

## Example with signal(2)

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 32

void signal_handler(int signal) {
    printf("Caught signal\n");
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, &signal_handler);
    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    struct addrinfo *addr_info;
    int info_result = getaddrinfo("localhost", "8080", &hints, &addr_info);
    if (info_result != 0) {
        printf("Getting address failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int sock = socket(addr_info->ai_family, addr_info->ai_socktype, addr_info->ai_protocol);
    if (sock == -1) {
        printf("Socket Failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int bind_result = bind(sock, addr_info->ai_addr, addr_info->ai_addrlen);
    if (bind_result == -1) {
        close(sock);
        printf("Bind Failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int listen_result = listen(sock, 8);
    if (listen_result == -1) {
        close(sock);
        printf("Listen Failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Waiting...\n");
    int accept_fd = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);
    if (accept_fd == -1) {
        close(sock);
        perror("accept");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Got fd %d\n", accept_fd);
    char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    int n;
    while ((n = read(accept_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
        printf("%.*s\n", n, buffer);
    }
    close(sock);
}
```

## Example with sigaction(2)

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 32

void signal_handler(int signal) {
    printf("Caught signal\n");
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = &signal_handler;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    struct addrinfo *addr_info;
    int info_result = getaddrinfo("localhost", "8080", &hints, &addr_info);
    if (info_result != 0) {
        printf("Getting address failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int sock = socket(addr_info->ai_family, addr_info->ai_socktype, addr_info->ai_protocol);
    if (sock == -1) {
        printf("Socket Failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int bind_result = bind(sock, addr_info->ai_addr, addr_info->ai_addrlen);
    if (bind_result == -1) {
        close(sock);
        printf("Bind Failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int listen_result = listen(sock, 8);
    if (listen_result == -1) {
        close(sock);
        printf("Listen Failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Waiting...\n");
    int accept_fd = accept(sock, NULL, NULL);
    if (accept_fd == -1) {
        close(sock);
        perror("accept");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Got fd %d\n", accept_fd);
    char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    int n;
    while ((n = read(accept_fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0) {
        printf("%.*s\n", n, buffer);
    }
    close(sock);
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete, usable example program.

Comment: I felt they were a bit too long for the post originally, but I've posted the examples that these were derived from in the OP.

Comment: "I understand that sigaction is more modern and that I should be using it over signal, but I'm quite curious why it provides this difference in functionality." it's historical some implementation do this, other don't, use use sigaction, and you will not have any problem.

Comment: Please stop do that `memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));`, just `struct addrinfo hints = { .ai_family = AF_UNSPEC, .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM};` we are not in 1989.

Comment: Is that to say that the functionality I desire is simply system dependant and not a guarantee in my current method?

Comment: ["Portability

The only portable use of signal() is to set a signal's disposition to SIG_DFL or SIG_IGN. The semantics when using signal() to establish a signal handler vary across systems (and POSIX.1 explicitly permits this variation); do not use it for this purpose. POSIX.1 solved the portability mess by specifying sigaction(2), which provides explicit control of the semantics when a signal handler is invoked; use that interface instead of signal()."](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signal)

Comment: That still does not answer the question of why `sigaction` provides this functionality. All it tells me is that `signal`'s behavior is implementation defined.

Comment: ["On BSD ... Furthermore, certain blocking system calls are automatically restarted if interrupted by a signal handler. ... By default, in glibc 2 and later, the signal() wrapper function does not invoke the kernel system call. Instead, it calls sigaction(2) using flags that supply BSD semantics."](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) Just read the manual ! And sigaction just provide his default semantic again read the manual.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I very much did look through the manual but I must have missed that.

Comment: I might add that it is unsafe to call printf() from a signal handler.  See "man 7 signal-safety" on Linux ( [see this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On BSD and Linux, `signal()` is equivalent to `sigaction()` with `sa_flags` set to `SA_RESTART`.  If you set that flag in your `sigaction()` code, it will behave the same as your `signal()` code.  If that's not what you want, then you must only use `sigaction()`.

Notes from the [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) (which also apply to BSD and OS X):

> On BSD,
>          when a signal handler is invoked, the signal disposition is not
>          reset, and further instances of the signal are blocked from being
>          delivered while the handler is executing.  Furthermore, certain
>          blocking system calls are automatically restarted if interrupted by a
>          signal handler (see signal(7)).  The BSD semantics are equivalent to
>          calling sigaction(2) with the following flags:

```
       sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for something exactly like this.