# Read blocks again after returning from signal handler

Tags: c, signals, system-calls, errno

I have written a very small test program to check the value of `errno` when `read()` is interrupted by a handled signal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

void handler(int sig){
    printf("signal: %d\n", sig);
}

int main(){
    signal(SIGINT, handler);
    char arr[10];
    read(0, arr, 10);
    perror("emsg");
    return 0;
}
```

According to everything I know and the man page on `read(2)`,

```
EINTR  The call was interrupted by a signal before any data  was  read;
              see signal(7).
```

`read` should return `-1` and set `errno` to `EINTR`. However, the output of the program suggests that it blocks again on `read` after returning from the signal handler.

This makes absolutely no sense to me and I cannot figure out what is going wrong.

Here is the output I got:

```
$ ./a.out
^Csignal: 2
^Csignal: 2
^Csignal: 2
^Csignal: 2
hello
emsg: Success
```

My question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912). The latter does not talk anywhere about what happens when syscalls are interrupted. The crux of that discussion is which should be used.

Additionally [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52180202/7906473) on the same thread says that `signal()` calls `sigaction()` underneath, so why is the behaviour in case of system calls different for the two?

Comment: Signals set up using `signal` could have different behavior between different Unix-like systems. Therefore you should always use [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) where you can specify the wanted behavior.

Comment: On a slightly related note, the value of `errno` is for almost all system calls *unspecified* unless the previous function actually failed. You *always* should check for failure before checking `errno` (which `perror` do).

Comment: You also can not safely call `printf()` from within a signal handler.  [Footnote 188 of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188) even states "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  [POSIX allows you to safely call async-signal-safe functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04).  The list of async-signal-safe functions on Linux can be found on [the `signal-safety` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).  Note that `printf()` is not on either list.

Comment: @AndrewHenle as I said, this is just a sample program that was supposed to demonstrate the use of `perror()`.

Comment: Okay, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52231219/7906473), `signal` sets `sa_flags` to `SA_RESTART` before calling `sigaction()`. Thus the restart of `read()`. Voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to everything I know and the man page on `read(2)`,
>
> ```
> EINTR  The call was interrupted by a signal before any data  was  read;
>               see signal(7).
> ```
>
> `read` should return `-1` and set `errno` to `EINTR`.

You are reading too much into that.  `read()` *can* return -1 and set `errno` to `EINTR`, which combination should be interpreted to mean that it was interrupted by a signal (before any data were read).  It's even safe to say that if `read` fails on account of being interrupted by a signal, then that's the way to expect it to manifest.  But that does not mean that `read` is guaranteed to fail in the event that a signal is received while it is blocking.

> However, the output of the program suggests that it blocks again on
>   read after returning from the signal handler.

That is indeed one possible behavior.  In particular, it is part of the BSD semantics for `signal()` and signal handling, and that is the default for Glibc (subject to the `_BSD_SOURCE` feature-test macro), so that's what you would expect by default on both Mac (because BSD) and most Linux (because Glibc).  The "Portability" section of [the manual page for Glibc's implementation of `signal()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) goes into the matter in some detail.

> Additionally this answer on the same thread says that `signal()` calls
>   `sigaction()` underneath, so why is the behaviour in case of system
>   calls different for the two?

The key thing about `sigaction()` is that it provides mechanisms for specifying all the details for the handling of the signal whose disposition is set, including, notably,

- whether (certain) system calls resume after the signal is handled;
- whether the signal disposition is reset upon receipt of the signal; and
- whether the signal is blocked while its handler is running.

Thus, if some implementation of `signal()` operates by calling `sigaction()`, that has no inherent implication for these or other ancillary behaviors upon subsequent receipt of the signal.  Nor does it mean that registering a handler for that signal directly via `sigaction()` must produce the same effect as doing so indirectly via `signal()` -- it all depends on the arguments to `sigaction()`.  The caller gets to choose.

Note in particular the advice from the manpage linked above:

> The  only portable use of `signal()` is to set a signal's disposition
>   to `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`.  The semantics when
>          using `signal()` to establish a signal handler vary across systems (and POSIX.1 explicitly permits  this  variation); **do not use it for this purpose**.

(emphasis in the original.)

Supposing that you want system calls *not* to be resumed after being interrupted by `SIGINT` and handled by your handler, you get that from `sigaction` by avoiding specifying `SA_RESTART` among the flags.  Most likely, you don't want any of the other flags, either, so that would mean something (for example) like this:

```
// with this form, flags and signal mask are initialized by default to all-bits-zero
sigaction(SIGINT, & (struct sigaction) { .sa_handler = handler }, NULL);
```